# How to find next available date inline

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this demo sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iexvfvQVHUc8BooAxpDg8awf6CDpv80b6Z_etBNPc0M/edit?usp=sharing

What I need is an `arrayformula` is to find inline the next available date from Col "C" and Col "D" dates, and apply colors depending on it

Also, want to have a "Past" in the dates already past

I have in Col F my expected result, cuz is hard to explain exactly what I need

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY(IF(LEN(C2:C), 
 IF((C2:C<TODAY())*(D2:D<TODAY()), "Past",
 IF((C2:C<TODAY())*(D2:D>TODAY()), "On Going now", )), ),
 "where Col1='Past' or Col1='On Going now'"),"");
 QUERY(IF(LEN(C2:C), 
 IF((C2:C>TODAY())*(D2:D>TODAY()), "Next Available", ), ),
 "where Col1='Next Available' limit 1")},
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, thank you, it works great, but I have added a line where the dates are occurring now, how can I add "on going now" ?

Comment: and if there is no past dates, it seems is not working, thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks, is working, the only problem is when there are not past dates I'm getting N/A